# Calculate the sum of first 45 numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate the arithmetical sum of first 45 numbers, where $a_n= (1-\sqrt3)n+2\sqrt3$.

I tried with all the formulas, but it seemes that none really work...

Comment: You mean the sum?  Well, what goes wrong when you try?  Hint :  for any constant $c$ the distributive law tells us that $\sum (c\times n) = c\times \sum n$.

Comment: What is the first number? $a_0$ or $a_1$?

Comment: Please edit to show your efforts and to clarify the question.  I am guessing you mean "the sum" and not "the sequence" but you should clarify.  Also, do you mean $\sum_{n=0}^{44}a_n$ or $\sum_{n=1}^{45}a_n$ or something else altogether?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe it's $a_1$

Comment: I assume that you mean *the average*.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  As you can see from the comments, some people are guessing you mean "the sum" while others are guessing you mean "the average" but why should we have to guess at all?  Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: The sum has to be calculated not the average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply take the series as an arithmetic progession and solve.
Answer, in my opinion is:
45*(23 - 21√3)
PS: As far as I have understood, you wanted the sum of first 45 TERMS of this series, right?

Comment: The answer is correct but how did you get 23 - 21√3

Comment: Got it, it really was an easy question....

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

An arithmetic sequence is linear, so that the average of the terms is equal to the average of the extreme terms. The sum easily follows.